# Is there a way to publish custom metrics from AWS Glue jobs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue

I'm using an AWS Glue job to move and transform data across S3 buckets, and I'd like to build custom accumulators to monitor the number of rows that I'm receiving and sending, along with other custom metrics. What is the best way to monitor these metrics? According to this document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitoring-awsglue-with-cloudwatch-metrics.html I can keep track of general metrics on my glue job but there doesn't seem to be a good way to send custom metrics through cloudwatch.

Answer (score -1):

Consider [enabling continuous logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuous-logging-enable.html) on your AWS Glue Job. This will allow you to do custom logging via. CloudWatch. Custom logging can include information such as row count.

More specifically

1. [Enable continuous logging for you Glue Job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuous-logging-enable.html)
2. Add `logger = glueContext.get_logger()` at the beginning of you Glue Job
3. Add `logger.info("Custom logging message that will be sent to CloudWatch")` where you want to log information to CloudWatch. For example if I have a data frame named `df` I could log the number of rows to CloudWatch by adding `logger.info("Row count of df " + str(df.count()))`

Your log messages will be located under the CloudWatch log groups `/aws-glue/jobs/logs-v2` under the log stream named *`glue_run_id`* `-driver`.

You can also reference the "Logging Application-Specific Messages Using the Custom Script Logger" section of the AWS documentation [Enabling Continuous Logging for AWS Glue Jobs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuous-logging-enable.html) for more information on application specific logging.

Comment: The OP clearly asks for custom metrics. You are answering about logging.

Comment: "I'd like to build custom accumulators to monitor the number of rows" won't be achievable via. metrics it will need to be done via. logging